# Unorderable types: int() < list()

Tags: python-3.x

```
next_number = []

for i in range(len(fib)):

    while next_number < [10]:
        next_number = fib[i] + fib[i + 1]
        fib.append(next_number)

print(next_number)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
euler_fibbonacci([0, 1])
File "C:\Python33\euler_fibbonacci.py", line 17, in euler_fibbonacci
while next_number < limit:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

Why he gives me this error because next_number is list and [10] is also a list.

Comment: Tip for the future: as a general rule, if Python says that something is an `int`, and you think it's a `list`, it's not Python who's confused. :^)

Answer (score 2):

The first pass through your `while` loop you do this:

```
next_number = fib[i] + fib[i + 1]
```

`fib[i] + fib[i + 1]` is an `int`.  The next pass starts by checking if that `int` is less than [10], which throws the `TypeError`.